# Optimizr, Is it secure or spam?

Tags: spam

I received a mail from optimizr.net. They say that I have some errors in my web
I never click to links on mail. So I went to google and they have a nice web. They say that their tool is to check errors in a website. It is free.

But I cannot find any information about that company. Is it a secure place? How are the owners? How do they make money?

Thank you

Comment: Sending unsolicited (mass) emails is the very definition of spam. Please also see this meta question about ["secure" questions](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/is-x-secure-question-anti-pattern). They are often closed as too broad, off-topic, or opinion-based. You may improve your question by eg asking if optimizr has spread malware in the past. How they make money seems off-topic here, as it's not about security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use services advertised by spammers. You are just encouraging them. Also, the fact that they resorting to illegal methods like email spam to advertise their services should tell you all you need to know about their business ethics and how much you can trust their advise.

There are lots of other services out there to check your website for common problems, like the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/). But that's a topic for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If you check the IP address that optimizr.net resolves to (178.63.88.243) - it is on at least one Blacklist.  Based on this I would error on the side of caution and say that it is spam.

Comment: How about sources?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title with a [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming) quote:

> Electronic spamming is the use of electronic messaging systems to send unsolicited messages

So, yes, that is spam.

Let's have a closer look:

- You get unsolicited email
- The site owners are protected by a whois proxy
- It seems fishy to you
- Such a service is available already from a known company for free

The first one is a no-brainer, that's the (a) definition of spam. The others are indicators to just walk away and go with the non-fishy alternative.

On the other hand, the IP the domain resolves to (178.63.88.243) is clean for most blacklists and hosted in Germany, where regulations on websites are rather strict.

Yet, the HTML that is delivered to `curl` of their main page does not comply to those strict laws. That may be another clue to just leave it alone, and maybe tip their hoster about it.